# VB.net striping an integer to 2 places

Tags: vb.net, number-formatting

I am trying to calculate a checksum value for a string of numbers. The numbers values are from 0-255 and I need to add them all together for a sum total. I need the sum total to be from 0-255 by stripping off all higher order bytes. I have tried to use a Byte as the value 0-255 but it gives me an overflow when above 255.

```
        For i = 0 To 15

        intValue = Convert.ToInt32(strData(i), 16) '// Hex string to Interger calculate for Checssum

        Checksum = Checksum + intValue            '// Add all the data lines to checsum


         Next i
```

This worked,

```
       HexCheckSumValue = Checksum And &HFF
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?  Are you unable to calculate the checksum?

Comment: Adding is not the problem,  I need to convert the checksum total to a byte. if checksum = 257 or hex(101) I need to strip off higher byte of 1 to get 01

Comment: Keeping the lowest byte is as simple as `Checksum And &HFF`. If you are guaranteed to have positive values, you could use `Mod 256` instead. But, if you have a negative `CheckSum`, then `Mod` will return a negative value, which will not fit into a Byte, if that is your goal. The bitwise operation probably gives a better context of what you're trying to accomplish, as well.